# How to compare the output of the "head" command applied to two different files?

Tags: bash

I want to diff the output of the `head` command applied to two separate files:

```
diff <(head -n 1 file1.csv) <(head -n 1 file2.csv)
```

I got the structure of the command from a similar question: [How do I diff the output of two commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229447/how-do-i-diff-the-output-of-two-commands)

But all that happened is that the top lines of each file were printed. So I'm not sure if it's diffing or not. Am I reading the output correctly?

How do I diff the output of the `head` command applied to two different files?

Comment: "Am I reading the output correctly?" What was the output you got?

Comment: I thought the output was the same, but there was a small difference that I couldn't easily see. The answer to this question was perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` is meant to print different lines only. The fact that you got those lines printed means they're different. Take these two as example:

```
# lines different, have output
$ diff <(head -n 1 /etc/passwd) <(head -n1 input.txt)
1c1
< root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
---
> hello world
# same file, first lines aren't different, no output
$ diff <(head -n 1 /etc/passwd) <(head -n1 passwd.copy)
$
```

Note that even slightest change should be detected by `diff`, so for example if I add a single trailing space in `passwd.copy` those two first lines are not the same anymore, even though at first sight they look so:

```
$ diff <(head -n 1 /etc/passwd) <(head -n1 passwd.copy)
1c1
< root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
---
> root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

See also [Understanding diff output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81998/85039)

Comment: That's why GNU `diff` has a rather large number of options dealing with whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

If the output of `diff` isn't sufficiently clear, consider using a more advanced tool, like meld, or my person choice: `vimdiff`. Using a similar example like @Sergiy, this is what Vimdiff shows me:

[image]

As can be seen, the extraneous whitespace is highlighted. More advanced diff highlighting can be obtained using [the DiffChar plugin](https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim) (see my post on [Vi & Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/500/205) for an example).